# Is there a way to get a number that will always return True whether or not if its > or < than an integer?

Tags: python

```
a = random number

b = magic number

if a < b:
    print(True)
if a > b:
    print(True)

outputs: True /n True
```

For all values in variable a, it will always pass any greater than or less than conditions.

I mainly need it for recursion so I can make a recursive function that takes in a nested list an returns the maximum and minimum values.

Currently I have this and wondering if there was any way to make it cleaner:

```
def max_min(L):
    '''
    >>> L = [1, [], [45, [32]]]
    >>> max_min(L)
    (45,1)
    '''
    if L == []:
        result = (None, None)
    elif type(L[0]) == list:
        first, second = max_min(L[0])
        max, min = max_min(L[1:])
        if first != None:
            if max != None:
                if first > max:
                    max = first
            else:
                max = first
            if min != None:
                if first < min:
                    min = first
            else:
                min = first
        if second != None:
            if max != None:
                if second > max:
                    max = second
            else:
                max = second
            if min != None:
                if second < min:
                    min = second
            else:
                min = second
        result = (max, min)
    else:
        first = L[0]
        max, min = max_min(L[1:])
        if max != None:
            if first > max:
                max = first
        else:
            max = first
        if min != None:    
            if first < min:
                min = first
        else:
            min = first
        result = (max, min)
    return result
```

Comment: ??? Numbers do not return anything.

Comment: I mean pass through any condition

Comment: I did give an example

Comment: I believe the answer is no but really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you can use `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` for something arbitrarily large and small but not one number to mean both. By why not `flatten` the list then just use python's builtin `max()` and `min()`

Comment: Its a recursive exercise so everything is expected to be done with recursion. Flattening a list and then finding the maximum and minimum using purely recursion means going into the list more than once. Currently I just find the maximum / minimum by going into it once.

Comment: He can't do that having potentially nested lists.

Comment: @jimmyjimmy Oh, if the goal really is not to iterate through the list multiple time, then I guess my solution can't be used either. :/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no.

You can have a name holding the `True` value and simply check it if you want, though it'll always be true... but you could put it at None otherwise, which will be evaluated as `False`.

So instead of setting the variable to this magic number if need be, you could set a variable to `True` or `None`.

I see you have posted an example, I'm gonna go through that.

Edit : To clean your example, you could start your function with: 
    `[x for x in L if x is not None]` (or any native function that does it better).

That way, no need to check if everything is None continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You can `flatten()` the list recursively using a generator, meaning you only go through the list once, e.g.:

```
In []:
def flatten(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

def max_min(L):
    f = flatten(L)
    try:
        min_ = max_ = next(f)
    except StopIteration:
        return None, None

    for x in f:
        if x < min_:
            min_ = x
        elif x > max_:
            max_ = x
    return max_, min_

max_min([1, [], [45, [32]]])

Out[]:
(45, 1)
```

You can combine them into a single function:

```
In []:
def max_min(iterable):
    max_ = min_ = None
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            x, y = max_min(item)
        else:
            x = y = item

        if max_ is None or (x and x > max_):
            max_ = x
        if min_ is None or (y and y < min_):
            min_ = y

    return max_, min_

max_min([1, [], [45, [32]]])

Out[]:
(45, 1)

In []:
max_min([])

Out[]:
(None, None)
```